# android winmerge filter rules

Tags: android, filter, winmerge

I want to use winmerge to merge two directories containing android projects. I wnat to merge only source files (.java ) , resource files ( layout / values/ drawable )

Can anyone help me with the rules for fileter.
This is the first time iam using winmerge.
I tried the following

```
 ## This is a directory/file filter for WinMerge
name: Java 
desc: Suppresses various binaries found in JAVA and svn source trees
## Ignore Java bin files
f: \.class$
f: \.jar$
f: \.eclipse$
f: \.classpath$
f: \.project.properties$
```

but i think last 3 which i added are not right
i can still see the following files in my list of compared result which i dont want

org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs

project.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify whether the filter is inclusive or exclusive.

Try to add:
def: include

or just make your rules exclusive:

def: exclude
f: \.java$
f: \.xml$
... and so on

Comment: May be some syntax error in my filter.   the one below is giving me expecte result . I had to change last three lines to be more specific                                                                                                                                                                          ## This is a directory/file filter for WinMerge
name: Java 
desc: Suppresses various binaries found in JAVA and svn source trees

## Ignore Java bin files


f: \.class$
f: \.jar$
f: \.prefs$
f: \.classpath$
f: \.properties$